# Load googlemaps api before AGM Map

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm trying to load the google maps API independently of the AGM Maps Module.  I'm trying to do this because in certain cases I want to access Google Maps API without using the AGM Module.  For instance, if I want to load a street view I need to make a call to the Google Maps service I want the API already loaded and ready to use.  The problem arises because the AgmCoreModule in the app.module takes care of loading the Google API like so:

```
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
        libraries: ['places', 'drawing', 'geometry']
    })
```

This is fine for loading a map using the AGM component.  The script is appended to the index.html file and everything works fine.  However, if I want to access the Google Maps API without having instantiated a map the AGM module hasn't appended the Google API script and 'google' is undefined.

Is there a way of loading the Google Maps API without using the forRoot() function on the AgmCoreModule?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by using the MapsApiLoader service.  No need to touch anything in app.module or change how AgmCoreModule is initialised.

```
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';


 constructor(
    private _mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader
  ) { }

this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: More convenient solution, no need to touch app module

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by using the MapsApiLoader service too. I needed to create HealtMap, but @agm/core don't have support, then i used this to load googleMapsApi and create a map.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AgmCoreModule, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';

import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment['apiKeyMaps'],
      libraries: ['visualization'],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div #gmap class="map-heat-container" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

declare var google: any;

interface Marker {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;

  map: google.maps.Map;
  heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer;

  constructor(
    private mapsApiLoader: MapsAPILoader,
  ) { }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    });
  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
      zoom: 3.5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-14, -54),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      zoomControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

    this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.getPoints(),
      map: this.map,
    });
  }

  getPoints() {
    // create points
    let markers: Marker[] = [
      { "lat": -23, "lng": -46 }, { "lat": -24, "lng": -53 }, { "lat": -23, "lng": -46 }
    ];

    // transforming points
    return markers.map(point =>
      new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng));
  }
}
```

I needed install @type/googlemaps and add *googlemaps* to tsconfig.json to use *var google* in app.component.ts

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Demo:** [StackBLitz](https://angular-agm-healtmap.stackblitz.io)